# Django template: Invalid block tag: 'endif', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am getting an error saying my template is not correct.

The error goes like: Invalid block tag: 'endif', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

My code is here, the bug is on the last line. Which part is not correct?

```
{% if entries %}
{% for entry in entries %}
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        (% if entry.scammer_name %}
        <div class="row no-gutter result-wrapper control-group">
            <div class="col-lg-3 result-label">
                <label class="control-group result-padding">
                    suspect's name:
                </label>
            </div>    
            <div class="col-lg-9 result">
                <label class="control-group result-padding light-font">
                    {{ entry.scammer_name }}
                </label>
            </div>    

        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</section>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is that the only code?

Comment: @Rohan No, I have edited it... The complete version is as showed

Answer (score 1):

Add `{% endfor %}{% endif %}` to the last line of code.

Comment: Change `(% if entry.scammer_name %}` to `{% if entry.scammer_name %}`

Answer (score 0):

For loops require endfor tags

```
{% if mike %}
  {% if jake %}
    {% for x in squid %}
      {{ x.do_stuff }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}{# closes jake tag #}
{% endif %}{# closes mike tag #}
```

Comment: Actually there is, I didn't put them here. The complete version is as showed but there is still problem.